# How to make string from a text file in Python 3?

Tags: python

```
path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\wordlist.txt"
word_list = open(path, 'r')
list = [x for x in word_list.split(" ")]
```

How can I open a file, so that I can make it into a string and eventually turn that string into a list? I've tried with `split()`, but it seems that text files can't just be split, although they are read.

Comment: Your code opens the file, but doesn't read anything.  `word_list` is the file handle (a.k.a. descriptor).  Check a tutorial on file handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with open`

**Ex:**

```
path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\wordlist.txt"
l = []
with open(path, "r") as infile:    #Read file
    for line in infile:            #Iterate over each line
        l.append(line.split())     #split by space and append
```

Comment: @Dreikasehoch If you need more insight than that visit: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 0):

`word_list.readlines()` will give the list itself as per row ending